# Выбрать одинаковые группы

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица

```
GroupId | ComandID
1       |    1
1       |    2
1       |    3 
2       |    1
2       |    2
3       |    2
4       |    3       
4       |    1
4       |    2
```

Необходимо выбрать все GroupId которые имеют одинаковый набор CommandID, т.е это 1 и 4

Comment: Укажите версию SQL Server - это важно.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуем решить задачу по шагам.

```
  SELECT GroupId, XXX(CommandId)
    FROM GroupCommands
GROUP BY GroupId
```

Я обозначил `XXX` агрегирующую функцию, которая могла бы дать гарантированно различный результат для различных наборов `CommandId`. Если бы все `CommandId` были степенями двойки (1, 2, 4, 8, 16, …), мы могли бы просто их сложить, с помощью функции `SUM`.

Но если это не степени двойки, что можно сделать? Начиная с 2017 года MS SQL поддерживает функцию `STRING_AGG`. В отличии от арифметического сложения, конкатенация строк чувствительна к порядку операндов, то есть е является коммутативной операцией. Поэтому нам придётся упорядочить таблицу по `GroupId`, `CommandId`, чтобы всегда обеспечивать нужный порядок. К счастью, это упорядочивание может быть сделано в самой функции `STRING_AGG`. Функция также приведёт целый тип к строке перед конкатенацией.

```
SELECT   GroupId, STRING_AGG(CommandId, '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY GroupId, CommandId) AS `CommandIds`
  FROM   GroupCommands
GROUP BY GroupId
```

В результате такого запроса мы получим:

```
| GroupId | CommandIds |
|       1 | '123'      |
|       2 | '12'       |
|       3 | '2'        |
|       4 | '123'      |
```

Если сгруппировать эту выборку по полю `CommandIds`, и посчитать количество `GroupId` в каждой группе, то количество больше единицы подскажет, где у нас есть повторения.

```
  SELECT CommandIds
    FROM (SELECT GroupId, STRING_AGG(CommandId, '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY GroupId, CommandId) AS `CommandIds`
            FROM GroupCommands
        GROUP BY GroupId)
GROUP BY CommandIds
  HAVING COUNT(GroupId) > 1
```

Теперь нам нужны `GroupId`, но взять их негде, поскольку они были свёрнуты при группировке. Мы должны снова повторить ту же операцию, что и в первый раз, и наложить фильтр на `CommandIds`:

```
SELECT   GroupId, STRING_AGG(CommandId, '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY GroupId, CommandId) AS `CommandIds`
  FROM   GroupCommands
GROUP BY GroupId
  HAVING CommandIds IN
         (
         SELECT CommandIds
           FROM (SELECT GroupId, STRING_AGG(CommandId, '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY GroupId, CommandId) AS `CommandIds`
                   FROM GroupCommands
               GROUP BY GroupId)
       GROUP BY CommandIds
         HAVING COUNT(GroupId) > 1
         )
```

Запрос, конечно, нетривиальный. Может быть здесь предложат более простое решение, я такого придумать не смог.

**UPDATE**

Очень важные дополнения в комментариях. Обратите внимание!

Comment: в STRING_AGG желательно использовать разделитель, иначе, например, группа состоящая из одного CommandId 12 будет равна группе из двух CommandId 1 и 2

Comment: Внутри группы достаточно `WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CommandId)`

Answer (score 1):

Вы не указали диалект *SQL*. Вот вам решения для *SQLite* и
*PostgreSQL*:

```sql
-- SQLite >= 3.25
SELECT GroupID
  FROM (
  SELECT GroupID
       , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY group_concat(CommandID)) AS GroupGroupCount
    FROM (
    SELECT *
      FROM GroupCommands
     ORDER BY GroupID, CommandID
  ) AS GroupCommandsSorted
   GROUP BY GroupID
) AS GroupCounts
 WHERE GroupGroupCount > 1
 ORDER BY GroupID
;
```

```sql
-- PostgreSQL >= 9.6
SELECT GroupID
  FROM (
  SELECT GroupID
       , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY array_agg(CommandID)) AS GroupGroupCount
    FROM (
    SELECT *
      FROM GroupCommands
     ORDER BY GroupID, CommandID
  ) AS GroupCommandsSorted
   GROUP BY GroupID
) AS GroupCounts
 WHERE GroupGroupCount > 1
 ORDER BY GroupID
;
```

Не знаю, можно ли проще; возможно, коллеги подскажут.

Comment: Работаю в MSSQL